# Plate theory vs FEA

Tags: finite-element-method, abaqus

[image: plate modelled in Abaqus]I’ve modelled a plate in Abaqus FEA, and I also calculated the Stress and deflection by hand using plate theory-

Why is it that plate theory and simulation deflection and Bon Mises stress values vary please? I didn’t make any specific assumptions when calculating? Is the FEA the one that’s wrong then?

Comment: In both cases you have inevitably used some assumptions and you could provide more information about them. For example, which boundary conditions did you use, which plate theory did you use for hand calculations and which elements and materials did you use in FEA. Very important think in FEA is also small/large deflections.

Comment: in addition to the above - has your plate theory calculated von mises stress or some other component? without know a lot more details, no one could say which of your theory or FEA is wrong. both could be wrong or both could be correct either